# Function that adds a div of a particular class

Tags: javascript, css

In my CSS I have a particular class for a `div`

```css
div.videl
{
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;  
   background-color: #39275b;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

and then a function to add `div`s of that class:

```javascript
this.addVideo = function()
{
      var newVidElement = document.createElement("div");
      newVidElement.class = "videl";
      newVidElement.innerHTML = "<p>(" + ++this.numVids + ") <textarea class='vidtxt'></textarea></p>"
      document.getElementById("vidplaydiv").appendChild(newVidElement);
}
```

However, for some reason, that function is not correctly applying the CSS properties when I test it out. See this page http://jaminweb.com/YoutubePlaylist.html and click the Add Another Video button. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt that pure dom element does not have any `class` property, it should be `className`, note that there is not always a correspondence between attribute in HTML and property in DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`className` is the name of the attribute you're trying to set.

```
newVidElement.className = "videl";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know the property name of the HTML attribute, You can always use setAttribute, for example:

```
newVidElement.setAttribute('class','videl')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the JavaScript code as below -

```
this.addVideo = function()
{
  var newVidElement = document.createElement("div");
  newVidElement.className = "videl";
  newVidElement.innerHTML = "<p>(" + ++this.numVids + ") <textarea class='vidtxt'></textarea></p>"
  document.getElementById("vidplaydiv").appendChild(newVidElement);
}
```